# Partial TFS Upgrade

Tags: tfs

I've running 2013 TFS Server.  We have multiple Projects in a single ProjectCollection.  However, we just inherited a bunch of projects from a company we just aquired, and they have all thier code in a 2010 TFS server.  I need to migrate the projects from this 2010 instance of TFS into our 2013 TFS server.

I've read about doing a complete 2010 migration to 2013, but one of the steps there is to uninstall 2013 and re-install after attaching the databases from the older 2010 server.

Since this isn't an option, as we already have 2013 projects in our 2013 TFS server, I'm wondering what else I can do for this migration.

Comment: Why not upgrade the TFS2010 to TFS2013, then take their project collection?

Comment: I guess I will do that.  What is the simplest means of upgrading a 2010 server?

Comment: See the answer by @MrHinsh below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should upgrade your 2010 to 2013 before you move the collection across. As you may have version issues with SQL and Windows you might be best using a temporary server that you restore the TFS 2010 databases to and upgrade to 2013.

Once you have upgraded your server to 2013 you can easily detach and attach to your existing server.

Comment: Just to clarify: There are a number of known issues around Detach/Attach migrations. These do not seem to be very well documented, or at least I only know about them through internal communications with the Product Team. Many of these issues have recently been resolved with the release of TFS 2013 update 4. The problem is that there is a chance of corruption on Detach from an older version of TFS. TFS 2013 update 4 has been patched to detect this corruption. Older versions might not notice them. This is why it is recommended to upgrade 2010 to 2013u4 first and then move using detach/attach.

Comment: Use a temporary environment if needed. Also, if you're combining two companies, I suspect that you're also doing a Domain move, in which case you need to be extra careful.

Comment: If you do a domain move incorrectly you can end up with two accounts for each person and no way to resolve history for an indevidual.

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to uninstall TFS 2013, you can attach 2010 to 2013 directly. I suggest you do the following:

- Detach TFS 2010 collection using TFS 2010 management console
- Backup 2010 collection database using SQL server management studio
- Restore this backup on the SQL server which is hosting TFS 2013 server databases
- Open TFS 2013 management console and attach 2010 collection to it. This step will perform the upgrade, so once it's done you can start working with this collection on the 2013 server.

Another thing I would suggest is doing this on the test server first.

Comment: Do not do an attach upgrade. It is less likely to work than an actual upgrade and is not recommended...

Comment: Downvoted due to issues with Detach/Attach upgrades with versions of TFS lower than 2013u4. It's a very often used practice, but it's not the safest way until both source and target environment are fully up to date.