# Can we upgrade Microsoft TFS Server 2013 to Microsoft TFS Server 2018?

Tags: tfs

Basically we have existing TFS 2013 running in PROD, can we just install TFS 2018 in a new machine and restore the DB? 
Please guide me with the upgrade from 2013 to 2018

Comment: Hi Cece Dong - MSFT
I tried installing TFS 2018 in a local VM and then took the PROD TFS 2013 DB backup and restored and followed the configuration wizard..... but it failed to load the site also it gave error converting the custom data types created in our 2013 version...
Will it work if we try moving to TFS 2015 and then from there move to 2018.. Please suggest

Comment: Also one more query: Can we migrate from TFS 2013 to any higher version even if we have some custom data fields in 2013 version. at the moment apparently our custom fields are returning conversion error...Please suggest

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid your SQL Server version doesn't meet TFS 2018's requirement. As TFS 2018 only supports **SQL Server 2017** and **SQL Server 2016 (minimum SP1)**.

You need to go through article [Upgrade your deployment to the latest version of TFS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfs-server/upgrade/get-started) before doing upgrade. And follow the steps in article [Upgrade scenario walkthrough for Team Foundation Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfs-server/upgrade/walkthrough) to upgrade your TFS. Summarize the steps here:

> 1. **Prepare your environment**. The first step is to check the [system requirements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfs-server/requirements) for TFS 2018. Upgrade SQL Server is
>      necessary for your scenario. Including SQL Server, you also need to check other system
>      requirements and prepare the environment.
> 2. **Expect the best, prepare for the worst**. You must have a complete and consistent set of [database backups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfs-server/admin/backup/config-backup-sched-plan) in case something
>      goes wrong.
> 3. **Do the upgrade**. Once the preparation is done, you'll need to install the new version of TFS to get new binaries, and then run
>      through the upgrade wizard to upgrade your databases.
> 4. **Configure new features**. Depending on what version you upgraded from, you may need to [configure each team project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/customize/configure-features-after-upgrade) to gain access
>      to some of the new features made available.

Here is a useful blog for your reference:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/rob/2016/12/22/upgrading-from-tfs-2013-to-tfs-2017/

Answer (score 1):

Even if the detach/attach upgrade is possible, it is not recommended to go that way and you could find more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27111869/partial-tfs-upgrade) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45583855/tfs-upgrade-from-2013-to-tfs-2017-without-detaching-the-collection) why is that. You could still go that route but at least you would be aware of the possible issues.

For the safest way to go here, would be to make an actual upgrade of your systems from TFS 2013 to TFS 2018. However, due to the [TFS requirements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfs-server/requirements), you would have to make something like that approach to make it possible:

From TFS 2013 upgrade to either TFS 2015 or TFS 2017. Based on your current SQL Server that you are using, if that is SQL Server 2012 you would have to go first to TFS 2015, upgrade your SQL Server to be SQL Server 2016 (minimum SP1), and afterwards proceed with the second upgrade to TFS 2018.